Text-to-speech webpage reader ignores forms
I have a pretty simple file to test out Text-to-speech accessibility:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" value="1" aria-labelledby="check1-label" />
        <label id="check1-label" for="check1">This is an input label</label>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

I'm using read-aloud Chrome / Firefox extension as it seems to be one of the most popular extension on that matter. It simply ignores forms.
Is there anything I'm missing?

Maybe raise a support issue with https://readaloud.app/

About screen readers and TTS extensions
Such browser extensions aren't at all representative of users in needs of screen reading or TTS because of an impairment (blind, partially sighted, dys-troubles, etc).
All those users use software that can read the screen globally everywhere on their device and not only in the browser.
Whatever their authors can say, these extensions are far from feature complete for a serious use by an user with real accessibility needs.
They are more intended for users who want TTS occasionnally but don't need it all the time. For example to transform quickly a text into an audio book, for foolish people who don't want to read, or maybe children.
Note that there are far superior dedicated apps to make an audio book or to transform a few paragraphs of text into speech, though.
For you as a developer/designer, if your goal is to test the accessibility of your site, it basically means that you aren't testing with the right tools real users with accessibility needs really use everyday.
In other words, you are missing your target, your tests are void, you are wasting your time.
You should test accessibility with the real softwares users use in the real life instead, so to really experience how it is about. There aren't 36 ways, you should run a screen readers in your machine.
For example, NVDA on windows, VoiceOver on Mac/iPhone/iPad, Talkback on Android. All of them are free and VoiceOver and Talkback are normally even readily available without the need to install anything.
ABout your code
True screen readers like Jaws, NVDA, VoiceOver and Talkback follow more or less well accessibility and ARIA standards. All of them shouldn't have any major problem reading your page as presented. I don't see any major error.
There is an useless redundency, though.
Since your <input> is already correctly linked to your <label>, you don't additionally need to link it with aria-labelledby. You should remove aria-labelledby.
This is totally superfluous, and it might be what's causing it to not be read by your browser extension.
However, TTS browser extensions can follow standards mor or less well, or not at all, and aren't expected or required to, so it's difficult to say if the behavior you observe is a bug or is intended, nor what you should do exactly to fix it (if it's fixable).
According to accessibility standards, it's definitely wrong, but since such browser extensions aren't primarily addressed to users with disabilities, something different might have been intended with reason.
